# What is the least dusty Earthen Plaster mixture to use on interior walls?

Tags: construction

What Earthen Plaster mixture is least dusty for use on interior walls?  The Earthen plasters I've seen, usually some mixture of earth, manure (horse or cow) and sand are pretty dusty.  They work, but, well, it'd be nice to have a more cohesive mixture for those sensitive to dust.

Comment: I take it you're talking about dust generated on an ongoing basis by rubbing/bumping the walls after construction is complete?

Comment: Yes.  It brushes off pretty readily ;)

Answer (score 3):

You could put in an additive (like cooked flour paste) or use a finish layer to protect and keep the dust down. The Wikipedia article has lots more info http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earthen_plaster
I remember another source of info but can not find it. I will update this answer if I can find it.